# VB.net: highlight full row without affecting cell backcolor

Tags: vb.net

[datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdQER.jpg)

hi guys, Good day! I'm doing a ticketing system with color code in 1st and 2nd column in my datagrid. My question is, how can I fullrowselect my datagrid without affecting the back color of my datagrid  in 1st and 2nd column. Please see my image sample

Comment: Pretty sure that's not VBA.  Maybe read that tag description again,,,  VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

`dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` is used to control this color. So set that to your prefered colors. There is more information on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx

You may need to do it dynamically if you're customizing the background colors so you could handle the CellFormatting event and make the changes in there.